# Spring Security - Account Authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working on a project where a user can only view info of his account.
Here are example APIs:

> http://example.com/clients --> only admin could call
>
> http://example.com/clients/1 --> admin and client with id=1 could call
>
> http://example.com/clients/2 --> admin and client with id=2 could call

Hope that you understand what I mean.

**First solution**:

At first, based on the authentication token when the user login, I will throw an exception if he tries to access info of other account (of course if he's not the admin). The solution works well.

**Second solution**:

I try to do the same thing with Spring Security but I stuck at authorizing the patterns. Do you have any idea how I could do the same thing with Spring Security?

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/clients").hasRole("ADMIN");
//I could not go further with each client
```

Any idea will be appricated. Thanks.

Comment: Will you provide your spring security configuration details ? That will help us to understand better.

Comment: I could not go too far with Spring Security. I just do some config and I think it's too complicated to go further. Please review the code I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying security in config file you can apply this on method itself.

Please remove `antMatchers("/clients").hasRole("ADMIN")` from Configuration file.

And update you methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clients")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
```

And another method as :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clients/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')")
```

This will work!

Comment: The first one may work but the second I think no. How can I prevent the user with id=1 from viewing the info of user with id=2?

Comment: Well if you want to achieve that then, you  can do one thing, remove Id from URL and fetch current logged-in user from session and return details. This way you don't can  prevent user with id 1 to fetch details of user with id 2. If you have any more doubts feel free to ask.

Comment: this is a possibility but if we want to extend the resource like: `/clients/1/transactions`, we have a problem.

Comment: No I don't think so. You can use same logic there as well. Just remove userId from URL and fetch it from session. Using id in URL is not a good practice.

Comment: OK. I get it. I could implement the return based on the token/cookies of logined user. 

I don't think adding id in URL is a bad practice. It's natural and free-work at the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point to not fast-deliverable but different option. It can be done with `ApiRequestInterceptor` and `SecurityContextHolder`*. In this interceptor, you can prehandle the request. You need three tables for role, authorizations and their relations. Respect to role of request owner, you can fill `SecurityContextHolder`.

```
public class ApiRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    //get token
    List<String> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuthorities.addAll(token.getRoles());
    //get authorized pages via service
    final List<String> authPages= service.getAuthPages(grantedAuthorities);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authPages)
    return true;
}
```

}

You can use the context holder in any controller, also. I'm open for any feedback because I might not express well.

*: When a request comes, it is processed on a new thread, and each thread has a different `SecurityContextHolder`. Here is the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html